# How to Swipe in iOS using Appium

Tags: java, ios, swift, selenium, appium

I am trying to swipe down a modal view in iOS using Appium with java.

I have tried this two ways unsuccessfully:

```
JavascriptExecutor js2 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

 HashMap<String, String> scrollObject2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
 scrollObject2.put("x", "200");
 scrollObject2.put("y", "550");
 scrollObject2.put("direction", "down");
 js2.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject2);

 TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
 action.press(PointOption.point(200, 550)).moveTo(PointOption.point(200, 700)).release().perform();
```

What I am doing wrong? is another correct way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it using js script executor.

No need to add coordinates like you did, just try something like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
JavascriptExecutor js = driver; 
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject); //or "mobile: swipe"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void fingerSwipe(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, long timeInMillis){
PointerInput touchAction = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "touchAction");
Interaction moveToStart = touchAction.createPointerMove(Duration.ZERO, PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), startX, startY);
Interaction pressDown = touchAction.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg());
Interaction moveToEnd = touchAction.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(timeInMillis), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), endX, endY);
Interaction pressUp = touchAction.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg());

Sequence swipe = new Sequence(touchAction, 0);
swipe.addAction(moveToStart);
swipe.addAction(pressDown);
swipe.addAction(moveToEnd);
swipe.addAction(pressUp);

driver.perform(Arrays.asList(swipe));
```

}

I use selenium interactions package to perform a swipe using JAVA and appium. Try using something similar to above code in WebDriverIo for Appium versions - 1.15.0 and above. You just need to pass input parameters depending upon the swipe you want to perform.

'long timeInMillis' is the time period of the swipe.